# Topology induced by family of seminorms is smallest topology that makes then continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let’s consider a collection of seminorms $\{\|\cdot\|_a, a\in A\}$ on a vector space V then my professor defined their induced topology as the topology generated by the finite intersections of open balls under different seminorms. I.e. $U \subseteq V$ is open if for every $x \in U$there exists a finite set $F \subseteq A$ and an $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t.:

$$
\bigcap_{a \in F}\{w \in V:\|w-v\|_a < \varepsilon\} \subseteq U
$$

Then we had a theorem that this topology is the same as the initial topology of the seminorms, i.e. the coarsest topology that makes all seminorms continuous.

But I must be getting something wrong here because if I consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and my collection of seminorms consists only of the euclidean norm then the smallest topology that makes it continuous consists only of „circles“ and „rings“ centered at the origin (because the only pre-images under the euclidean norm are „circular“ things centered at the origin), isn’t it? But the topology induced by the euclidean norm is of course the standard topology, which has way more open sets. So what am I getting wrong?

Comment: You're right, it's the smallest topology that makes $V$ into a topological vector space and for which all seminorms are continuous.  There is a smaller topology, but it's not the topology of a topological vector space.  The addition and scalar product are not continuous.  It's not invariant to translations for instance.

Comment: But in the induced topology, as given by your professor, aren't the open balls centered at any elements $v\in V$? Then in the same way, in your example of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean norm, doesn't the induced topology consist of open balls centered at any elements $v\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and not just centered at the origin?